# Raspberry Pi 4 controlling a Servo without shaking

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hardware, gpio, servo

I've been trying to control a mg995 Servo by changing the duty Cycle with the RPi.GPIO library, but the Servo ended up shaking a lot. I've been reading a lot of Threads about this issue and I know, that using the RPi.GPIO library is causing the issue.
I then tried to use the pigpio library but it's unfortunately not available for the RP4.
I know that buying a specific hardware could help out but I want to try it with software first.
Is there another way to controll a Servo without the shaking? I want to run the Servo through python code btw

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com is a better fit for this sort of hardware question.

Comment: I've used pigpio with a raspberry pi 4. I would try again.

Comment: @TeejayBruno you got a link that was useful for you? I couldn't get along with the documentation and all the other stuff was also to abstract for me unfortuntaelly

Comment: the official docs sum it up well. See the following example -- http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_frequency

Answer (score 1):

If the driving is not done at a too high PWM frequency then you can create a solution by using SYSFS driver, if you need high frequency the problem is maybe hardware and not software to control at the oscilloscope. If you are able and want to do without any lib then you can write directly the gpio registers of the SOC through memory-map with `mmap`

Answer (score 0):

As I tested before, software PWM is unstable and the servos can shake a lot, hardward PWM is quite acurrate, but the pi has only 2 hardware PWM channels.
The best way may be add an external PWM module (PCA9685 for example).